# antlr3 c# code generation

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I'm able to successfully generate C# code (CSharp2) for my grammar written using ANTLRWorks. But I would like to do the same without all the debug statements that are generated by default. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the generator without the `-debug` option.

I got this from here: http://www.antlr.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2009-November/036849.html

Comment: Thanks.. Is it possible to do the same from ANTLRWorks?

Comment: I don't know, is it?  I suppose there is a properties page somewhere with build options you can set.